# What are the tags in android manifest to limit a app to be available only for phones on Playstore?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I would like to make my app available only on phones i.e devices whose screen sizes are less than 5.5 inch.How do I limit my app from being visible on tablets on Play store?

Answer (score 2):

You can also declare based on the **device size**.

*For your example you can try setting max width to `600 (non-tablet)`:*

```
<supports-screens android:largestWidthLimitDp="600"/>
```

Here is another example based on `min width`

```
<!-- Support only devices with min 600dp witdth (Tablets)-->
<supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

Comment: Will this allow installation of the app from non-Google sources?

Comment: @Ahmed probably it will work, however i am not sure about that. Check if any documentation is available about that

Answer (score 0):

This will work -

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

and other way

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="false"
                      android:xlargeScreens="false"
                      android:largestWidthLimitDp="600"
                       />
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

For more info - [Click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps)

Comment: This is what I have in my manifest,but this is not listing latest flagship devices likeGalaxy s6,Nexus 6,Moto x G2 and others.

Comment: Nope.Support Screen is displaying all the tablets too as supported devices.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below settings.This seems to be correctly filtering tablets outand including only phones including the Galaxy s6,nexus 6 etc .

```html
<compatible-screens>
  <!-- all small size screens -->
  <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
  <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
  <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
  <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
  <!-- all normal size screens -->
  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />

</compatible-screens>
```